# Amazon S3 sync to folder in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I am using the code sample [amazon-s3-sync](https://github.com/chao/amazon-s3-sync) to sync data to Amazon S3. So far the code is working well, but I am unable to make it sync to a folder object in a particular bucket.
For example: to a folder within a bucket,

testbucket->testfolder

My code: S3Object.cs

```
 internal S3Object(S3Connection connection, string BucketName, XmlNode node)
        : base(connection)
    {
        m_key = node.SelectSingleS3String("s3:Key");

        //m_key = "lamp_531d7a/" + node.SelectSingleS3String("s3:Key");
        m_eTag = node.SelectSingleS3String("s3:ETag");
        m_size = int.Parse(node.SelectSingleS3String("s3:Size"));
        m_lastModified = node.SelectSingleS3Date("s3:LastModified");
        m_buckname = BucketName;
    }

    internal S3Object(S3Connection connection, string BucketName, string Key)
        : base(connection)
    {
        m_key = "test/" + Key;
        //m_buckname = BucketName;
        m_buckname = "jdemo01";
    }
```

m_key is where I appended my key name aka the folder name

Thank you.

Comment: Add some code to your question please to show what have you tried and what isn't working

Comment: I changed the code in S3Object.cs